# Creating a new vector by sampling an existing one, but with the probability of being drawn conditional on the position in the sequence

Tags: r, sample

I have a simple vector like this

```
V1 <- seq(1:21)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

I want to sample V1 to create a new vector (V2) of the same length without replacement, but I want to condition the probability of drawing a given value based on position in sequence V2.

Specifically, for numbers =10 or <10 (i.e., values in the first half of V1), id like there to be an 80% chance that they appear in the first half of V2. 20% of numbers will essentially migrate to the opposite side of the vector from V1 to V2.

Any thoughts on how to do this (with flexibility in in the specific percentage or migrant numbers), is much appreciated!

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
sample(V1, prob = ifelse(V1 <=10, 0.8, 0.2))
```